# A question about the Vitali set.

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $X=[0,1)$ and we define on $X$ the relation $\sim$ in the following way:$$x\sim y\quad\iff\quad x-y\in\mathbb{Q}.$$ The relation $\sim$ is an equivalence relation. For all $\alpha\in[0,1)$ the equivalent class is $$E_{\alpha}:=\{y\in[0,1)\;|\;y-\alpha\in\mathbb{Q}\}.$$ The class $E_\alpha$ is countable for all $\alpha\in[0,1)$, indeed if $\alpha\in\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1)$, $E_\alpha=\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1)$, while if $\alpha\in\big(\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}\big)\cap [0,1)$, $y\in E_\alpha$ if and only if $y=(\alpha+q)$, where $q\in\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1).$

> **Question 1.** Is my reasoning correct to show that each class $E_\alpha$ is countable?

Therefore $$[0,1)=\bigcup_{\alpha\in[0,1)} E_\alpha.\tag1$$  From $(1)$ it is clear that exists an uncountable infinity of classes $E_\alpha.$

For the axiom of choice exists $V\subseteq [0,1)$ such that $$V\cap E_\alpha=\{x_\alpha\}\quad\text{for all}\;\alpha\in [0,1).$$ The set $V$ is called the *Vitali set*. Let $\{q_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ an enumeration of $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1)$ and we define for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ $$V_n:=\{x_\alpha+q_n\;\text{mod}\;1\;|\;x_\alpha\in V\}.$$I must prove that $$[0,1)=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} V_n.$$ Let $x\in\bigcup_{n} V_n$ then $x\in V_n$ for same $n\in\mathbb{N}$, therefore $x=x_{\alpha}+ q_n\;\text{mod}\;1$, where $x_\alpha\in V$, then $x\in [0,1).$ Let's proceed with the other inclusion: let $x\in [0,1)$ then $x\in E_\alpha$ for same $\alpha\in [0,1)$, in particular, since the classes $E_\alpha$ are disjointed $\alpha$ is unique, then $$x-x_\alpha\in\mathbb{Q},$$ in particular, since $x\in [0,1)$ and $x_\alpha\in [0,1)$ we have that $$x-x_\alpha\in\mathbb{Q}\cap (-1,1)\tag2$$

> **Question.** From $(2)$ how can I proceed to show inclusion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It is not entirely correct. For instance, you claim that$$y\in E_\alpha\iff y=\alpha+q\text{, where }q\in\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1).$$What if $y<\alpha$? Besides, there is no nedd to treat the cases $\alpha\in\mathbb Q$ and $\alpha\notin\mathbb Q$ separately.
2. Why induction? If $x-x_\alpha=q\in\mathbb{Q}$, then $q-\lfloor q\rfloor=q_n$ for some $n\in\mathbb N$ (since $q-\lfloor q\rfloor\in\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1)$) and therefore $x\in V_n$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Why if $x-x_\alpha=q\in\mathbb{Q}$, then $q=q_n$? $q_n\in\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1)$, while $x-x_\alpha\in (-1,1).$ 1. At this point how can I show that every $E_\alpha$ is countable?

Comment: I've edited my answer to the second doubt. What do you think now?

Comment: So are we using the fact that there is a bjection between $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1)$?

Comment: No, I did not use that.

Comment: Last chance: $(-1,1)\ni x-x_\alpha=q\in\mathbb{Q}$, then $q\in\mathbb{Q}\cap (-1,1)$, therefore $\lfloor q \rfloor=0$. we know that $q_n=q-\lfloor q \rfloor$, then $q=q_n+\lfloor q \rfloor$, then $x-x_\alpha=q_n$.

Comment: I hope it's correct, thank you!

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: I think I wrote something wrong in my last comment: $q\in\mathbb{Q}\cap (-1,1)$, then $q\in\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1)$ or $q\in\mathbb{Q}\cap (-1,0)$. If $q\in\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1)$, then $x=x_\alpha+q_n$ for same $n\in\mathbb{N}$, as $x=x_\alpha+q_n<1$ we have $x=x_\alpha+q_n\;\text{mod}\; 1$. If $q\in\mathbb{Q}\cap (-1,0)$, then $x=x_\alpha+q_n-1$, because, in this case $\lfloor q\rfloor =-1$. Then as  $x_\alpha+q_n=x+1\ge 1$, then $x=x_\alpha+q_n\;\text{mod}\; 1.$

Answer (score 1):

One way to see countability of all classes is to note that the class of $x\in \mathbb{R}$ is just $[x]=\{x+q: q \in \mathbb{Q}\}\cap [0,1)$: every $x+q \in [x]$ is equivalent to $x$, as $x+q-x = q \in \mathbb{Q}$ and if $x \sim y$ then $q:=y-x \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $y = x+q \in [x]$.

So every class is in bijective correspondence with $\mathbb{Q}$ (via $q \to x+q$ for the class of $x$).

$[0,1)$ is a partition of classes so (assuming choice) there are $\mathfrak{c}=|\mathbb{R}|$ many different classes; if there are $\kappa \ge \aleph_0$ classes each of size $\aleph_0$, $|[0,1)|$ has size $\kappa \cdot \aleph_0=\kappa$ as well. So $\kappa=\mathfrak{c}$.

There is not *the* Vitali set but only *a* Vitali set (it depends on a lot of choices and every different choice for a representative of a class gives a different Vitali set).

To see that $[0,1) = \bigcup_n (V+\{q_n\} \pmod{1})$, let $x \in [0,1)$. Then $x$ is in $[x]$ and we have some unique $v \in [x] \cap V$ as a representative. So $x-v= q_k \pmod{1}$ for some $k$ so $x \in V+\{q_k\} \pmod{1}$.

Comment: Let's see if I understand what you said in the first part: we fix $\alpha\in [0,1)$ and we consider the map $f\colon \mathbb{Q}\to E_\alpha$ defined as $q\mapsto f(q):=q+\alpha$. The map $f$ is well defined and injective. Now, let $y\in E_\alpha$, then $y-\alpha\in\mathbb{Q}$, therefore $q:=y-\alpha$, then $y=q+\alpha$. Since $q+\alpha\sim\alpha$, $y=f(q)\in E_\alpha$. Correct?

Comment: @JackJ. Yes, that’s about it.